# how to filter out documents from mongo aggregation based on profile_id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below are 2 documents which i get from my view alongside other documents

```
{
    "_id": "ACTIONS_NOT_COMPLETED_4X:87f4e016-e181-4a65-94d8-34a08df24442",
    "profile_id": "87f4e016-e181-4a65-94d8-34a08df24442",
    "last_modified_date": {
        "$date": "2021-09-13T11:07:04.736Z"
    },
    "trigger_status": "PENDING",
    "event_type": "ACTIONS_NOT_COMPLETED_NX",
    "notification_type": "REWARD",
    "progress_status": "1/5",
    "event_occurence": 4,
    "event_trigger_date": {
        "$date": "2021-09-13T11:07:04.736Z"
    }
}
```

```
{
    "_id": "ACTIONS_NOT_COMPLETED_3X:87f4e016-e181-4a65-94d8-34a08df24442",
    "profile_id": "87f4e016-e181-4a65-94d8-34a08df24442",
    "last_modified_date": {
        "$date": "2021-07-13T11:07:04.736Z"
    },
    "trigger_status": "PENDING",
    "event_type": "ACTIONS_NOT_COMPLETED_NX",
    "notification_type": "REWARD",
    "progress_status": "1/5",
    "event_occurence": 3,
    "event_trigger_date": {
        "$date": "2021-07-13T11:07:04.736Z"
    }
}
```

As you can see both these documents have same profile_id,but i want distinct document based on profile_id?How can i do it in Mongo compass Aggregation ??

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

```
[{$match: {
  event_type: {
            $eq: "ACTIONS_NOT_COMPLETED_NX" 
            }
}}, {$sort: {
  event_trigger_date: -1
}}, {$group: {
  _id: {
    "profile_id": "$profile_id",
  },
  data: {
    $first: "$$ROOT"
  }
}}, {$unset: 
  "_id"
}, {$replaceRoot: {
  newRoot: "$data"
}}]
```